# redirect back to page after php code

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying the following code to update external content inside a div named "content1"

ajax.js:

```
var ajaxdestination="";

function getdata(what,where) { // get data from source (what)
  try {
    xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest?new XMLHttpRequest():
new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
catch (e) { /* do nothing */ }
document.getElementById(where).innerHTML ="<center><img src='loading.gif'></center>"; // Define the destination DIV id, must be stored in global variable (ajaxdestination)
ajaxdestination=where;
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = triggered; // when request finished, call the function to put result to destination DIV
xmlhttp.open("GET", what);
xmlhttp.send(null);
  return false;
}
function triggered() { // put data returned by requested URL to selected DIV
   if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) if (xmlhttp.status == 200) 
      document.getElementById(ajaxdestination).innerHTML =xmlhttp.responseText;
}
```

Inside my div I include 'page1a.php' with php, wich outputs a value from my database and contains a link to 'code1a.php' where I have a php code that updates this value. (This is just a test and will do more than update a value in the future).

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="getdata('tmpa/code1a.php','content1');">update value</a>
```

Inside code1a.php where I have a php code that updates my database, after the database has been updated, is there a way to update my div (content1) with 'page1a.php' again?
I have tried everything i could think of and search the web for a few days, but not found a solution to my problem.

The script can be found on: http://www.battrewebbsida.se/index2.php

Comment: Why don't you use $.post as ajax call method?
On callback function you can update your page by js manipulations

Comment: catch (e) { /* do nothing */ } should be catch (e) {return false;}

Comment: I'm sure there are better ways to do this but I'm not very skilled in javascript. I have no skills at all, and this is the only example i have found that almost does what i want. But I will look into you suggestions and see what I can find. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many variants to do this, your solution isn't best to do it, but here's the modified  your javascript code, which is that what you want.

**By Javascript**

```
    var ajaxdestination="";
    var tmpcache = '';
    function getdata(what,where) { // get data from source (what)
      try {
        xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest?new XMLHttpRequest():
    new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    catch (e) { /* do nothing */ }
    tmpcache = document.getElementById(where).innerHTML;
    document.getElementById(where).innerHTML ="<center><img src='loading.gif'></center>"; // Define the destination DIV id, must be stored in global variable (ajaxdestination)
    ajaxdestination=where;
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = triggered; // when request finished, call the function to put result to destination DIV
    xmlhttp.open("GET", what);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
      return false;
    }
    function triggered() { // put data returned by requested URL to selected DIV
       if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) if (xmlhttp.status == 200) 
          document.getElementById(ajaxdestination).innerHTML =tmpcache;
    }
```

**By PHP**

after doing your updates in 'code1a.php' send header location to your first 'page1a.php' file

```
header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'/page1a.php');
```

**NOTE:** dont forget about `ob_start()` at the top of script.

Comment: Thank you. Although using the header code did not work. The page only showed the loader. I guess the url got wrong or something. Removing the header code did take me back to page1a.php, but it didn't refresh the content. (But did increase the value as it should).
I'm not good at javascript at all. This is just an example i found that suited my purpose. And as you said, there are probably better ways to do this. If I had several divs on the same page, with different content and wanted to load a form and then update the content without the page to reload. What would be a better way to do it?